# Count and sum per day multiple tables without join

Tags: sql

I want count the number of orders invoices delivery and sum the amount of orders invoices delivery per day.
Like this:

```
date  nb orders  orders$     nb delivery   
day1     5        1234,56       3
day2     6        665,88        7
..
```

The first time I tried this, it was ok for one day but not for a week, for example:

```
SELECT  
  (SELECT COUNT(OPP.OPPNUM_0) FROM OPPOR OPP WHERE OPP.CREDAT_0=%1%),
  (SELECT SUM(OPP.OPPAMT_0) FROM OPPOR OPP WHERE OPP.CREDAT_0=%1%),
  (SELECT COUNT(SQH.SQHNUM_0) FROM SQUOTE SQH WHERE SQH.CREDAT_0=%1%),
  (SELECT SUM(SQH.YCUMHTSEL_0) FROM SQUOTE SQH WHERE SQH.CREDAT_0=%1%),
  (SELECT COUNT(SOH.SOHNUM_0) FROM SORDER SOH WHERE SOH.CREDAT_0=%1%),
  (SELECT SUM(SOH.ORDNOT_0) FROM SORDER SOH WHERE SOH.CREDAT_0=%1%)
FROM    dual
```

Comment: if OPP.CREDAT is a date use BETWEEN instead of =. Please add which DBMS are you using on tag

Comment: I dont think you can avoid joins here, as even if your query does not contain a join kehywords, still DBMS has to mix and match values as done in join (or cross product) what you can do is to use semi-join technique to reduce any join overhead

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't want to do `JOIN`s? Is it just a performance concern? If so, there might be other techniques you can use to improve performance with `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides built-in query for filtering by day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE anydatefiled >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```